# rails email activation page add email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used rails4.2.8, and ruby2.5.0;

I had the email_confirm.html.erb , which when user signup complete，jump to this html page , the html codes like this :

```
<% provide(:title, 'email activation') %>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 bgCo pdlr">
   <h3 class="pageItemTitle"><i class="fa fa-envelope text-yellow mr5"></i>email activation</h3>
   <h4 class="pd10 bgCo">Please Activation account:</h4>
   <div class="text-center">
   <span class="text-gray pbt20 ">The email had send to : <span class="text-yellow fs18"><%= current_user.email %></span></span>
 </div>
  <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="###">Go to the mailbox to check</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

The user_controller.rb about signup like this:

```
def create
@user = User.new(user_params) 
if @user.save
  log_in @user
  flash[:success] = "还差一步就注册成功了!"
  redirect_to :email_confirm
else
  flash.now[:danger] = '注册失败，请输入正确内容！'
  render :new
end
```

end

I want to get the `<%= current_user.email %>` corresponding website of the mailbox company,such `as xxx@gmail.com` corresponding `mail.google.com`,and add the url of the mailbox company to the `<a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="###">Go to the mailbox to check</a>`

I had complete the logic content such as:

```
s = "dafaaf@gmail.com"

tumple = ["mail.qq.com","mail.126.com","mail.163.com","www.yeah.net","mail.sina.com.cn","mail.yahoo.com","mail.sohu.com","mail.aliyun.com","mail.google.com"]
y = s[/([A-Za-z0-9]+)(@)(.*+)/,3]
tumple.each_index do |i|
  if tumple[i].include?y
    print(tumple[i])
  else if y==="gmail.com"
     print("mail.google.com")
       end
   break
  end
end
```

But now ,how can I add this logic content to the rails (or controller)?
Please help me ,thanks so much!

Comment: Did you get the `<%= current_user.email %>` in the `email_confirm.html.erb` page?

Comment: "I had the email_confirm.html.erb , which when user signup complete，jump to this html page , the html codes like this :" -> Please provide code piece that makes this `jump`and describe where this code is placed

Comment: @Emu yes, the <%= current_user.email %> had the right email content.

Comment: @ AntonTkachov thanks ， I had add the user_controller.rb relevant codes in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you've `current_user` object in `email_confirm.html.erb` page. In that object you got the **email** of the user. In that case, you can copy the mailbox code to `application_helper`

in **application_helper.rb** file:

```
def get_mailbox(email)
  email = email.split('@').last
  tumple = ["mail.qq.com","mail.126.com","mail.163.com","www.yeah.net","mail.sina.com.cn","mail.yahoo.com","mail.sohu.com","mail.aliyun.com","mail.google.com"]

  if email == "gmail.com"
    return "mail.google.com"
  else
    tumple.find { |t| return t if t.include? email }
  end
end
```

Now, in the view file **email_confirm.html.erb**

```
<a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="<%= get_mailbox(current_user.email) %>">Go to the mailbox to check</a>
```

Hope it helps!

**N.B. I din't check you're logic, also I did assume that you've a current_user object.**

Comment: thanks @ Emu , I had try as your codes ,but it seems that  `href="<%= get_mailbox(current_user.email) %>`   cann't get website of the email company , it gets nothing ...

Comment: @sylor_huang, it's because your method doesn't actually not returning anything. You need to change the code. Currently, it's just printing, not returning.

Comment: @ Emu thanks a lot , Do your mean that I should change the `def get_mailbox`  `print` to `return` ? I had changed it ,but  I cann't get the url in `email_cofirm.html.erb `  the url display none ....

Comment: you can change your helper code with the code given by sovalina in the other answer with a return value. Hope it'll work

Comment: @ Emu sorry , I cann't understand , I'm a beginner for rails ,if you have time , could you write the codes for me thanks so much~~~

Comment: answer edited. Please go through the answer carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You really should refacto your logic in a better ruby way

```
def get_mailbox
  email = current_user.email.split('@').last
  tumple = ["mail.qq.com","mail.126.com","mail.163.com","www.yeah.net","mail.sina.com.cn","mail.yahoo.com","mail.sohu.com","mail.aliyun.com","mail.google.com"]

  if email == "gmail.com"
    print "mail.google.com"
  else
    tumple.find { |t| print t if t.include? email }
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , how can I get the `get_mailbox()` result in the `email_confirm.html.erb`  , that is how can I write the codes in the `href`